# Каким образом создаётся экземпляр класса? с++

Tags: c++, классы, объекты

У нас есть простой класс `Point`:

```
class Point
{
public:
   float x, y;
   void Set(float x, float y)
   {
       this->x = x;
       this->y = y;
   }
}
```

Метод `Set`, насколько я знаю обычная функция,у которой первый параметр, указатель на объект. А что будет с полями `y` и `x`, они будут записаны в какую-либо таблицу или что-то другое? Где хранится описание этого класса, то есть оно хранится в оперативной памяти вместе с запуском exe-файла или оно будет действительно только на этапе компиляции. Я вас умоляю помогите мне с этим разобраться, заранее огромное спасибо:)

Comment: Встречный вопрос - с `int x;` у вас вопросов нет? Где хранится описание этого типа `int`?

Comment: Описание существует только во время компиляции. Во время выполнения под такой объект будет выделено 8 байт памяти (по 4 на каждый float)

Comment: Почему у метода Set первый аргумент это указатель на объект? У этой функции два аргумента типа `float` передаются по значению. члены-данные класса будут помещены в стек в порядке их объявления. То есть вы можете представить себе класс в виде прямоугольника и разделить его на столько частей, сколько полей есть в нём. (Но это если совсем просто) Получается, при создании объекта типа `Point` в стек будет помещено столько памяти, сколько в вашей архитектуре занимает тип `float`. Заходя немного вперёд: Если у вас описаны виртуальные функции,то для них будет создаваться таблица виртуальных функций

Comment: @mld8nk, первый аргумент существует неявно, и это действительно указатель на объект. Почитайте про thiscall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы определили переменные

```
Point p1, p2, p3;
```

то в оперативной памяти резервируется область под хранение всех полей этого класса: `x, y`. В зависимости от места определения переменной, это может быть в статической памяти, которая выделяется при старте программы (если определили переменную в глобальной области), или в стеке, стековая память выделяется при входе в тело функции (если вы определили эти переменные в теле функции. **Память под них выделяется столько раз, сколько переменных вы объявили**.

Если вы определили указатель на `Point`, и создали объект с помощью оператора `new`, всё происходит точно так же: резервируется память под две переменные, только память выделяется из кучи и происходит это в момент вызова оператора `new`.

Далее, независимо от способа выделения памяти, вызывается конструктор класса. Хотя он у вас и не определён, но конструктор по умолчанию всегда генерируется компилятором.

Если вы объявили эти переменные в глобальной области (в статической памяти), то они автоматически будут инициализированы нулями. Если в теле функции (в стеке) или с помощью оператора `new`, то они будут заполнены мусором, и их необходимо инициализировать вручную (это можно сделать в конструкторе).

Методы класса компилируются один раз, и присутствуют в коде в единственном экземпляре. Но к методу, в соответствии с соглашением о вызовах `thiscall`, прибавляется неявный параметр - указатель на объект, к которому применяется данный метод.